# mediawiki1.16.5 installation problem

Tags: oracle11g, mediawiki

I am installing mediawiki1.16.5 package but it shows some error when i configuring database. i am using oracle. can anyone tell me how to rectify this error.

thanks in advance.

Comment: "Some error," eh? Let me consult my crystal ball...

Comment: Hello sir, can you guide me in this regard.

Comment: DB hostname: localhost/orcl or localhost or ipaddress. which one is correct or what should i write.

Comment: It was very old post by me, I want to tell you that I was able to configure mediawiki1.17 with oracle 11g and it is running quite normal since 2010. It is really great tool for CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against installing MediaWiki on Oracle unless you're doing low-level testing of the Oracle database API -- it's unstable and may not work in the first place, so you need to be familiar with how it works or it'll just break on you.

You should definitely consider simply installing with MySQL, which is very well supported.